# How to capitalize first letter of each sentence AND give User the chance to change the letter to lower?

Tags: c#, console-application, capitalize, sentence

I implemented a capitalize after interpunctation. BUT how to implement it, that the user can go BACK and delete the first word or character because he wants to continue in lower-case?

```
KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if(EndOfSentence())
   {
       e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.Keychar);
   }
}
//
private bool EndOfSentence()
{
  //return true if end of sentence found
}
```

Example: If I write this sentence. I cannot go back and change the "I" to "i"! And I cannot change the "A" to "a" but I want to! How to code this?

Example Project here: http://www.filefactory.com/file/3ecbn51bhbrv/n/Capi.zip

The only Solution I see, is to save the current and previous key and check if backspace or delete was pressed like:

```
if (!EndOfSentence())
{
  previousKeyChar = e.KeyChar;
  return;
}
//
if(previousKeyChar.Equals('\b')) return;
else
e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
//
//
// And in the EndOfSentence I Check
// if the cursor is at the end of the text
if(textbox1.Text.Length != textbox1.SelectionStart)
  return false; //allow editing in the middle of the text
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways, but one is to store the entire sentence in a collection and check against the collection before modifying it again.

Comment: There may be better ways and I kindly ask for a solution this way without a collection to check against. How may it be solved in MS Offices Word or Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try changing your `EndOfSentence` function to only return true if you are also at the end of the input. That way, it should only capitalise characters typed at the end of the input, if you edit something in the middle of the text it should remain unchanged

Comment: I have tried this before but it fails if the user writes a sentence and edits the end of it.

Example:  This is a Sentence. A|nd if the user goes back to the "And" she can change the "A" to "a". But this fails if she tries changing the following A to a. A|

Comment: @user1338270 there is no `and` in "This is a Sentence". Can you try to explain that again?

Comment: Let | be the cursor. And let my whole previous comment be the Test-Case. Lets only return true for EndOfSentence if we are at the end of the input. Then the user can change the A|nd to a|nd. But the user cannot change the A| to a|.